# Sharepoint Mysite Documents

Tags: 2007, my-site, configuration

Relative Sharepoint newby here so be gentle! :-)

We have had a request to try to hide the documents section on user's my site pages. I have been trawling through pages and pages of sharepoint stuff but can't seen any obviouls way of doing it.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "documents section"?  Are you talking about the Personal and Shared Documents libraries that are part of a MySite?  Or documents that are listed on the user's profile page or something else entirely?  A solution would probably depend on which thing you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks Samual. The terminology is still a bit new to me at this stage - thrown in at the deep end certainly applies :-). I do mean the Documents libraries on MySite. Basically, we have had a breach of security with confidential documents being available to everyone. It would be a nice to have to hide all documents on the public mysite pages until we can perform an audit of each sites permission. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ["classic" blog post by Steve Peschka](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184%7D&pID=794) on customizing My Sites content using feature stapling and a custom ASP.NET control to mess with web parts on a newly provisioned My Site (among other things).

The concepts probably apply here.

Comment: It's the only supported way to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat possible. However, since My Sites are customizable and personal, they can add the web parts back into the pages. You would just have to create a feature that would remove them on initial creation, but the user will still be able to add them back.